# Puerto de gestión en SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

El problema es que estoy tratando de establecer el puerto de gestión para el springboot actuator a 9091, pero se mantiene siempre en el puerto de la aplicación, en este caso el 6421, he intentado varias documentaciones que he encontrado, pero no funcionan, esta es mi configuración (he omitido algunos valores):

```
server:
  port: 6421
  connection-timeout: 10000
  servlet:
    context-path: /stack
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
    max-threads: 20
    max-connections: 20
    accept-count: 20
    min-spare-threads: 1
    graceful-shutdown-wait-seconds: 25

es:
  company:
    utils:
      audit:
        request-response:
          enabled: true
          properties:
            application: ${spring.application.name}
            exclude-url-patterns:
              - /actuator/**
              - /swagger-ui.html
              - /webjars/**
              - /v2/api-docs
              - /csrf

spring:
  jackson:
    time-zone: Europe/Madrid
    mapper:
      accept-case-insensitive-enums: true
    deserialization:
      accept-single-value-as-array: true
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
    date-format: ${app.api.date-format}
  application:
    name: someone-management
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        name: ${spring.application.name}
        namespace: stackOverflow-dev
        enabled: true
        enableApi: true
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api

###########################
# Management and monitoring
###########################
management:
  port: 9091
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
      exposure:
        include: info, health, metrics, prometheus, loggers
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  security:
    enabled: false
```

En sí el resto de propiedades las está aplicando correctamente, ya que puedo cambiar el path o los endpoint que se muestran, pero el puerto no cambia nunca.

También tengo un bean de configuración pero no he encontrado el modo de modificarlo por aquí:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class PrometheusCustomConfig {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    @Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return registry -> registry.config()
                .commonTags("application", appName);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: Hola, estás en StackOverflow en ESPAÑOL, por favor [edit] tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. [ask] - [tour]

Comment: Buenas, perdona, estoy tan acostumbrado a leerlo todo en inglés que me salió automático, de echo no sabía ni que eran dominios distintos. Un saludo.

Comment: Qué versión de spring boot usas? Cómo está definido el pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente estás usando la versión incorrecta de la documentación (y en tu pregunta no incluyes el pom, así que nos tocó adivinar.

Para 2.x esa propiedad se configura en

`management.server.port`

Y tú pareces estar usando la configuración de Actuator 1.x.

Comment: Correctísimo, tendré esto en cuenta en el futuro, gracias, un saludo